# How do I get this jQuery Youtube Popup to work on my local website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-javascript-api

this is my first post. I'm very new and still learning everything but I'm really stuck here. I'm experimenting whit a website localy. I'm trying to get Abhinay's jQuery YouTube Popup player to work on my site. http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

I get the popup window and the video tries to load but it does not work. I have a feeling it got something to do whit it being local but I'm not sure. When serching I got results about CORS and JASON that might work? Could now find any simple explanation on how to use it, maybe someone can explain it a bit more simple.

This is the relevant code bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.youtubepopup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({ autoplay: 0 });
    });
</script>



<a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eYSpIz2FjU"
            title="jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin TEST">Test Me</a>
```

Remember I'm very new to webdesign and coding in general so if you could explain this simple I would be very thankful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open your console, any error?

Comment: I think, in file:///var/www/site/home.html url youtube player not work. you can change url to http://localhost/site/home.html.

Comment: no errors only one warning: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

The youtube player loads for about a minute and then says: The file or directory could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into it. It will not work from your local computer directly. It needs to be on a webserver. Of course, if you have WAMP (XAMP), EasyPHP, some other WebServer installed on your computer, or just Apache, then it will work.

The youtube script uses a method to determine your protocol, and will rebuild the link based on that. 
Or if you *really* want to use it on your LOCAL computer without any web server hosting it, you could do like this:

Open **jquery.youtubepopup.min.js** with notepad or notepad++ and find the following lines:

```
function getYouTubePlayer(URL, width, height) {
    var YouTubePlayer = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="' + width + '" ';
    YouTubePlayer += 'height="' + height + '" src="' + URL + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    return YouTubePlayer;
}
```

and change them to:

```
function getYouTubePlayer(URL, width, height) {
    var YouTubePlayer = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" style="margin:0; padding:0;" width="' + width + '" ';
    URL=URL.replace("file:","http:");
    YouTubePlayer += 'height="' + height + '" src="' + URL + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    return YouTubePlayer;
}
```

Emil